# appear an html element by clicking on a button with angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an html form (  ) , I want that it is displayed when I click on a button.
the declaration of the form is the following :

```
<div id = "formulaire" class="gl" >
```

and the button is :

```
<a href="#" ng-click="edit(u)">Edit</a>
```

I use angularjs in my code . Please help me.

Comment: Hm, do you also use Bootstrap?

Comment: yes i use bootstrap-3.3.5

Comment: You could also use the [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) functionality for the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It better to use a simple variable than a function in this case. I would also recommend using [controller scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) when setting variables instead of the [application scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) so you don't run into issues with the variables when your application becomes large.

I also picked `data-ng-click` over `ng-click` because it will allow the [html](/questions/tagged/html) to validate correctly (which can be checked using the [W3's validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)).

Try this...

```js
"use strict";
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("myController", function() {
    this.edit = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="ctrl.edit = !ctrl.edit">Edit</a>

    <div id="formulaire" class="gl" data-ng-show="ctrl.edit">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Field:</label>
                <input type="text" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [ngShow directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)? It ables you to show or hide a DOM element depending on whether the attribute expression resolves to a truthey or falsey value.

Answer (score 0):

Add model change on click

```
 <a href="#" ng-click="show = true">Edit</a>
```

And then display the form if model is true

```
<div id = "formulaire" class="gl" ng-if="show">
```

Comment: i have on the ng-click a function :
<a href="#" ng-click="edit(u)">Edit</a>
Can i use two ng-click ?

Comment: I assume edit(u) is a fucntion. In this case you can simply say $scope.show="true"; in your function